# How to get all the sum of individual id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sum

I have a table containing `jan_1,feb_1,jan_2,feb_2` columns.

Each column having amounts.eg the `st_id` has two rows. One is for `jan_1,feb_1` data and other is for `jan_2,feb_2` of amount.

I want a single row of each id. Now I got only one row of all the amt sum.

Query:

```
SELECT st_id,SUM(jan_1+feb_1) as amt1,SUM(jan_2+feb_2) as amt2 FROM 
fee_amount WHERE `st_id` IN (5,7,8);
```

Comment: add `group by st_id`

Comment: what does jan_1 + feb_1 stands for? and what is the different with jan_2 + feb_2?

Comment: Hi Robins. You seem to have forgotten to respond to all four helpful answers below, which were posted on the same day as you posted your question. Would you vote, comment or accept on those questions, as appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY st_id`. Thus you will get each row for each `st_id`.

```
SELECT 
 st_id,
 SUM(jan_1+feb_1) as amt1,
 SUM(jan_2+feb_2) as amt2 
FROM fee_amount WHERE `st_id` IN (5,7,8)
GROUP BY `st_id`;
```

**Note:** Aggregated function without `Group By` collapses the result set into one row.

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5421c/5/0)

Comment: Please check this query @Rose

Answer (score 0):

In your query add only `GROUP BY` clause(**`GROUP BY st_id`**) at last.

```
SELECT 
 st_id,
 SUM(jan_1+feb_1) as amt1,
 SUM(jan_2+feb_2) as amt2 
 FROM fee_amount 
 WHERE `st_id` IN (5,7,8)
 GROUP BY `st_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable way is to sum ( jan_1 + jan2 ) as Jan, while doing the same for feb data.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    st_id,
    SUM(jan_1 + jan_2) AS jan,
    SUM(feb_1 + feb_2) AS feb
FROM
    fee_amount 
WHERE 
    `st_id` IN (5,7,8)
GROUP BY
    st_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st_id,
       Sum(jan_1 + feb_1) AS amt1,
       Sum(jan_2 + feb_2) AS amt2
FROM   fee_amount
WHERE ` st_id ` IN ( 5, 7, 8 )
GROUP  BY ` st_id ` ;
```